# Как загружать аудио файлы после полной загрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, аудио

Как загружать аудио файлы, после полной загрузки страницы сайта ( имею в виду когда загрузится вся страница сайта `css`, `js`, фото и так далее, а в последнюю очередь чтобы загружались аудио файлы )?

```
$(function(){  

      $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="audio/notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg"><source src="audio/notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><source src="audio/notify.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>').appendTo('body');

        if(22==22){
          $('#chatAudio')[0].play();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать например плагин [Ion.Sound](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/index.html), то такой проблемы не возникнет. Там можно указать в конфиге, нужно ли предзагружать звуки.

Например:

```
ion.sound({
    sounds: [
        {name: "notify"}
    ],
    path: "static/sounds/",
    preload: false
});

// а потом в любой нужный момент просто вызвать
// звук загрузится только тогда, когда будет нужен

ion.sound.play("notify");
```

Если же вы хотите работать через ваш код, то хорошим решением будет разместить загрузку звуков в body.onload. Это событие будет вызвано только после того, как все-все остальные ресурсы будут загружены (включая внешние счетчики, файлы аналитики и прочее). Это можно сделать так:

```
$(document.body).on('load', function () {
    // здесь
});
```